# Feature selection for classifier

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I'm using a supervised machine learning algorithm on some big data. There is much more features than observations. To reduce the number of features, I would like to do some feature selection. However, there is one thing I'm confused about. May I do the feature selection *first*, using data from *all* observations, and then do the training and testing of the classifier?

Comment: no. feature selection=model buiding, and should only be done with training set. otherwise estimates provided by training set will be misleading.

Answer (score 4):

In any case you should always split your data into a development and a test set. You will look at the test set *only once*, which is when you evaluate the model you build, where model also includes the feature selection process.

*Never* use the test set during model selection.

Anything else is extremly dangerous in your setting. In case you need to look at the test set multiple times, you should have a range of test sets which you can add to your development set after each iteration.